# Why can't I declare a new character array in this unique pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

I'm trying to make a runtime id for an object. I have it done using a regular pointer, but I need to make it work with a unique pointer. Why can't I use `new` in the unique pointer? I get

> Error E0079   expected a type specifier.

On this line:

```
unique_ptr<char> idPtr(new char[DEVICE_ID_LENGTH]);
```

Here is the full file:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>


using namespace std;

constexpr auto DEVICE_ID_LENGTH = 10;
class Widget
{

public:
        //constructor
        explicit Widget(int nbr);

        ~Widget();
        
        void getID(char* s, const int len);
        
        std::string WhatIAm; 
        //char* idPtr = new char[DEVICE_ID_LENGTH];  //This needs to be initialized by the constructor


        unique_ptr<char> idPtr(new char[DEVICE_ID_LENGTH]);

        int getSize();

private:
        int widgetSize;
        int widgetNumber;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members) about default member initializers (bold emphasis mine):

> Non-static data members may be initialized in one of two ways:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. Through a *default member initializer*, which is a **brace or equals initializer** included in the member declaration and is used if the member is omitted from the member initializer list of a constructor.

Note that default member initialization using parentheses like in your code is not allowed here. Instead, it is interpreted as *member function declaration*, thus after opening bracket parameter list is expected, but you provide `new`-expression, so your compiler correctly complains that while your parameter list doesn't seem empty, it doesn't see type specifier for the first parameter.

Also note that you need `unique_ptr<char[]>`, not `unique_ptr<char>`, to manage arrays created by array form of new expression, so that its destructor knows it has to call `delete[]`, not `delete`, for held pointer.

So, to perform default member initialization like you want, you can use, e.g., braced initializer like this:

```
unique_ptr<char[]> idPtr{new char[DEVICE_ID_LENGTH]};
```

P.S. `using namespace std;` is bad practice usually, *especially* in header files. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).